# Trying to Merge or Concat two pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame in Databricks Environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I have two dataframes in Azure Databricks.  Both are of type: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame

The number of rows are the same; indexes are the same.  I thought one of these code snippets, below, would do the job.

First Attempt:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)


Error Message: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

Second Attempt:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

Error Message:  TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'> was passed
```

Comment: If you have a common column (say `ID`) in the 2 DFs, you can use join: `df.join(df2, ["ID"])`

Comment: I ended up joining on the index of both DFs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up converting the two objects to pandas dataframes and then did the merge using the technique I know how to use.

Step #1:

```
df1= df1.select("*").toPandas()
df2= df2.select("*").toPandas()
```

Step #2:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Done!

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue when combining two dataframes of same columns.

```
df = pd.concat([df, resultant_df], ignore_index=True)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Then I tried join(), but it appends columns multiple times and returns empty dataframe.

```
df.join(resultant_df)
```

After that I used union(), gets the exact result.

```
df = df.union(resultant_df)
df.show()
```

It works fine in my case.